# Manage multiple matching in prolog

Tags: prolog

Suppose you get in input a description of a graph, something like "A is near B" and you want to update your knowledge base.

Using Prolog I've decided to use this solution:

```
:- dynamic edge/2.

store(Desc):- Desc=[A,is,near,B],
          assert(edge(A,B)),
          write(A-B).


store(Desc):- Desc=[A,is,near,B,that,is,near,C],
          write(A-B),nl,
          write(B-C),
          assert(edge(A,B)),
          assert(edge(B,C)).
```

I'd like to extend the parsing to potential infinite sentences, like:
'1 is near 2 that is near 3 that is near 4 etc',
so what I'd like to do is something like (Idea expressed in pseudocode-like-notation):

```
  procedure store(Sentence)
  begin
  foreach 'X is near Y' in Sentence  assert edge(X,Y).
  foreach 'X that is near Y' in Sentence assert edge(X,Y).
  end
```

How can I achieve this in Prolog?

Comment: You should consider writing a predicate like `extract_edges(Sentence, Edges)` first instead of working directly with the database. It would be easier to implement and easier to trace / debug also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can do pattern matching and unification in a single step. Second, you need to make your predicate recursive. *Consume* the first words in that sentence (i.e. the first elements of the list) and let the recursive goal handle the rest:

```
store([A, is, near, B]):-
    assert_edge(A, B).
store([A, is, near, B, that|Other]):-
    assert_edge(A, B),
    store([B|Other]).

assert_edge(A, B):-
    ...
```

---

Another way to do that is to use `setof/3` and a built-in predicate for lists like `append/3`:

```
?- L = [a, that, is, near, b, that, is, near, c, that, is, near, d],
   setof(A-B, L1^L2^append(L1,[A, that, is, near, B|L2], L), Edges).

L = [a, that, is, near, b, that, is, near, c|...],
Edges = [a-b, b-c, c-d].
```

Comment: That seems to be a dependency-based parse tree represented as a single complex term. You need to make use of the pattern matching capabilities of Prolog. But this is a different problem than the one you asked here first. You should post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

A DCG approach could work well here:

```
store --> [A], is_near(B), { assertz(edge(A, B)) }, and_near(B).

and_near(_) --> [].
and_near(A) --> [that], is_near(B), { assertz(edge(A, B)) }, and_near(B).

is_near(A) --> [is, near, A].

store(L) :- phrase(store, L).
```

Then you'd use the query:

```
| ?- store([a, is, near, b, that, is, near, c, that, is, near, d]).

true ? ;

no
| ?- listing(edge).

% file: user_input

edge(a, b).
edge(b, c).
edge(c, d).

yes
| ?-
```

You can also use a DCG to extract to a list:

```
extract([edge(A,B)|Edges]) --> [A], is_near(B), and_near(B, Edges).

and_near(_, []) --> [].
and_near(A, [edge(A,B)|Edges]) --> [that], is_near(B), and_near(B, Edges).

is_near(A) --> [is, near, A].

extract(L, Edges) :-
    phrase(extract(Edges), L).

| ?- extract([a,is,near,b,that,is,near,c,that,is,near,d], Edges).

Edges = [edge(a,b),edge(b,c),edge(c,d)] ? a

no
| ?-
```

Comment: The second approach is particularly nice! +1! It is always good to keep side-effects separate from the core logic, so that you obtain pure relations that can be used in all directions. Once obtained, the edges can  be easily asserted with `maplist(assertz, Edges)`.

Comment: @mat, thanks :o). I had actually earlier today used that `maplist(assertz, Edges)` notion in my answer to the [OP's other similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035073/make-multiple-assert-basing-on-pattern-matching).